# making multiples tags on photos in facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api

it is possible? 
For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/tags/user1,user2,user3,etc
```

Actually, I'm looking for alternative to this:

```
  $friends = json_decode($facebook->api('/me/friends'), true);
  $friends = $friends['data'];
  foreach($friends as $friend) { 
    $id = $friend['id'];
    $name = $friend['name'];
          echo 'User='.$name.' state='.(PhotoTag($photo_id, $id) ? 'ok' : 'failed')."\r\n";
 }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it via the [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) feature of the Facebook Graph API.